# SQL - Multiplied Column Not summing correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I have to take two columns ( one quantity and one price) multiply the two together to get the issued cost ( per component) and then SUM them in the second . These parts are calculating correctly. The area I am having issues with is SUMMING these totals. When I summarize this area, I get an incorrect result.

Here is the full query ( Including a union all) 
The column I am having an issue summarizing is the 'Total Issued Cost' in the second query.
It should be taking the 'Issued Cost' column from the first query (T1.IssuedQty * T2.Price) and summing them.

The value I am receiving is not correct ( much higher)

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), T0.DOCNUM) AS 'Production Order'
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), ((T1.IssuedQty) * T2.Price)) AS 'Issued Cost'
    ,'' 'Total Issued Cost'
FROM OWOR T0
INNER JOIN WOR1 T1 ON T0.DOCENTRY = T1.DOCENTRY
LEFT JOIN IGE1 T2 ON T2.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry
    AND T2.BaseType = '202'
    AND T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN IGN1 T3 ON T3.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry
    AND T3.BaseType = '202'
LEFT JOIN IGN1 T8 ON T8.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry
    AND T3.BaseType = '202'
    AND T8.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN ORSC T4 ON T1.Itemcode = T4.ResCode
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ITT1.Code 'BOMCODE'
        ,ITT1.Father 'BomFather'
        ,ITT1.VisOrder
        ,ITT1.Quantity
    FROM ITT1
    ) ITT1 ON T0.Itemcode = ITT1.BomFather
    AND T1.Linenum = ITT1.VisOrder

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.DocNum 'Production Order'
    ,'' 'Issued Cost'
    ,Convert(NVARCHAR(100), (T1.IssuedQty * T2.Price)) AS 'Total Issued Cost'
FROM OWOR T0
LEFT JOIN WOR1 T1 ON T0.DOCENTRY = T1.DOCENTRY
INNER JOIN IGE1 T2 ON T2.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry
    AND T2.BaseType = '202'
    AND T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, if your table names are only 4 characters, it seems counterproductive to alias them to completely generic, uninformative 'Tx' names.  `WOR1.IssuedQty * IGE1.Price` is easier to verify than bouncing up and down to re-check what `T1` and `T2` are aliases of.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. I will work on having better aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the inner join to OWOR to a left join in the second query which may be increasing the numbers. Also, I did not find the sum function in the query, so I have added that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      CONVERT(nVARCHAR(100),T0.DOCNUM ) AS 'Production Order'
     ,CONVERT(nvarchar(100), ((T1.IssuedQty)*T2.Price)) as 'Issued Cost'
     , '' 'Total Issued Cost'
FROM OWOR T0 
INNER JOIN WOR1 T1 ON T0.DOCENTRY = T1.DOCENTRY
LEFT JOIN IGE1 T2 ON T2.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry and T2.BaseType = '202' and T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN IGN1 T3 on T3.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry and T3.BaseType = '202'
LEFT JOIN IGN1 T8 on T8.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry and T3.BaseType = '202' and T8.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN ORSC T4 on T1.Itemcode = T4.ResCode
FULL OUTER Join 
    (Select ITT1.Code 'BOMCODE', ITT1.Father 'BomFather', ITT1.VisOrder,ITT1.Quantity 
     from ITT1  ) ITT1 on T0.Itemcode = ITT1.BomFather and T1.Linenum = ITT1.VisOrder

Union All

SELECT 
    T0.DocNum 'Production Order'
    ,'' 'Issued Cost'
    , Convert(Nvarchar(100), SUM(T1.IssuedQty*T2.Price))) as 'Total Issued Cost'
FROM OWOR T0 
inner JOIN WOR1 T1 ON T0.DOCENTRY = T1.DOCENTRY
inner JOIN IGE1 T2 ON T2.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry and T2.BaseType = '202' and T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
Group by T0.DocNum
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Cant believe I forgot the sum.... I added that in there ( thank you!) and changed to both be on an inner join. Issue with that is it is still not totaling to the correct amount....

Comment: Hello! and other ideas... even when summing that way I receive a much larger number than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Changing field to include SUM(DISCINCT() Example: Convert(Nvarchar(100), SUM(DISTINCT(T1.IssuedQty*T2.Price))) worked.